# Jquery custom scroll bar with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, scrollbar

Here is the success section of a Jquery Ajax call in relation to the use of a custom scroll bar from http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ which appears to be very popular.

```
success: function (data) {
        $('#messages_div').html(data); 
        $('#messages_div').fadeIn(500,function(){$('#messages_div').mCustomScrollbar();});
       },
```

The div's content gets populated and then at the end of the fadein, it simply blanks out. No scrollbar, no content too!  I tried it with static content and it works fine. I have simplified the code here but I hope I have provided the relevant part. Any thoughts?

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: Thanks Rajesh but I switched to nicescroll and so far it is working fine.

Comment: Rajesh, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345568. I have reposted the problem with details. I had to ditch nicescroll. Hope you get to it. I desperately need some help here!